# Unable to deploy react app on AWS beanstalk, error code : 128 error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created a simple demo app at my local machine. It is running properly at local but when I am getting

> Error code: 128 Error

when try to deploy it on AWS beanstalk.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to set up AWS git commit access in your code.

Comment: I have set it up Bira but still didn't work

Comment: No need Git. avoid code commit and try